# AzureML - Custom R clustering model

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it currently possible to create a custom R clustering model, where you can define your own clustering model? Because AzureML does not let you connect Customer R Model with Train Clustering Model.

This is a critical limitation of AzureML when it comes to clustering.

Note: I know that you can create it in Execute R Script, but I want to be able to save the model so when new test data is inputted, I would assign it to the respective clusters.

Comment: Maybe you should split what you are trying to do in two separate tasks: first *cluster* your data (for instance with K-Means), then build and save a *classification* model (for instance K-Nearest-Neighbors).

Comment: Maybe use a less limiting tool than Azure instead.

Comment: mgr, you can just use the regular "train model" and "score model" modules for your custom R model. (The module names are not specific to clustering because your custom model could be of any type.)